# How to integrate $t^{m-1} \textrm e^{-ut}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

Could you please help me to compute $$\int t^{m-1} \textrm e^{-ut} \textrm dt$$?

Comment: Is $m$ integer?

Comment: @N74 What counts is that $\Re (m) > 0$ and $\Re (u) > 0$.

Comment: @1over137 we don't know what *tools* the OP knows to solve his problem. In this comment (and in your answer) you are implicitly assuming he knows complex analisys. If the problem is for $m$ integer you can find a solution using only real analisys.

Comment: @N74 There is noting in my answer that leads to complex analysis.. Everything I used is something taught in every Calculus I course.. I specified those assumptions otherwise the integral does not converge!

Comment: @1over137 I've never been taught about Euler gamma until my third Calculus course, after introducing it as the analytic continuation of the factorial of an integer. We just don't know what the OP *knows*, so better to ask before giving a correct answer he cannot understand.

Answer (score 3):

Change of variable

$$ut = z ~~~~~~~ \text{d}z = u\text{d}t ~~~~~~~ t = \frac{z}{u}$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\int z^{m-1}\ e^{-z}\ \text{d}z$$

TO evaluate this, if you have the indefinite integral, you can either integrate by parts $m-1$ times or try with a Taylor series of the exponential. In se second case:

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\int z^{m-1} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-z)^k}{k!}\ \text{d}z$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{u^m}\int z^{m-1} z^k\ \text{d}z$$

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{z^{m+k}}{m+k}$$

This is a well known series, which gives you:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{z^{m+k}}{m+k} = \Gamma(m) - \Gamma(m, x)$$

So finally

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\int z^{m-1}\ e^{-z}\ \text{d}z = \frac{\Gamma(m) - \Gamma(m, x)}{u^m}$$

**Special Function Involved**

- [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
- [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

**THE DEFINITE INTEGRAL**

If instead you're searching for something like

$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^{m-1} e^{-ut}\ \text{d}t$$

Then substitute in the same way to get

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\int_0^{+\infty}z^{m-1}e^{-z}\ \text{d}z$$

This integral is very famous and it's nothing but the Gamma Function, so:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}z^{m-1}e^{-z}\ \text{d}z = \Gamma(m)$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{u^m}\int_0^{+\infty}z^{m-1}e^{-z}\ \text{d}z = \frac{\Gamma(m)}{u^m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts
treating polynomial as first function and exponential part as second function.then use recurrence relation.

set $ut=z, t=\frac{z}{u}, dt=\frac{dz}{u}$
$\int t^{m-1} \textrm e^{-ut} \textrm dt= \frac{\int z^{m-1} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz}{u^m}=\frac{I_m}{u^m}$
where $I_m=\int z^{m-1} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz$
Integrate $I_m$ by part

$I_m=z^{m-1}e^{-z}+(m-1)\int z^{m-2} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz=z^{m-1}e^{-z}+(m-1)I_{m-1}$
Now replace $m$ by $m-1$

$I_{m-1}=z^{m-2}e^{-z}+(m-2)I_{m-2}$
$I_1=0$ and $I_2=ze^{-z}$
replacing these values, we get
$I_m=e^{-z}[z^{m-1} +(m-1) z^{m-2}+(m-1)(m-2) z^{m-3}+···+(m-1)!]$...
Put this value in original integral you are done..

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Substitute $x=ut$ and have a look at the [gamma-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: It's not the simple only Gamma function, since the integral is not definite.. But close enough.

Comment: @1over137 The question has been edited several times, and not by the OP himself. Let's hope this is enough for him. It would not surprise me.